# Spoiler markup does not break line for series of MathJax equations in post previews

Tags: bug, spoilers, mathjax, formatting

Putting a spoiler on MathJax equations does not work well sometimes, as reported [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14743/ages-of-a-and-b-self-reference-in-past) (1st answer).

For example,

> $$a=1$$ $$b=2$$ $$c=3$$

can be written using

```
> $$a=1$$
> $$b=2$$
> $$c=3$$
```

or

```
> $$a=1$$ $$b=2$$ $$c=3$$
```

**However**, writing

```
>! $$a=1$$ $$b=2$$ $$c=3$$
```

or

```
>! $$a=1$$
>! $$b=2$$
>! $$c=3$$
```

results in no line breaks in the preview pane. To see this in action, edit this post and look at this block:

> $$a=1$$
>  $$b=2$$
>  $$c=3$$

**Where have the line breaks gone?**

Comment: Okay, this **is** getting really weird. When I saw the preview to this meta post, there weren't any line breaks. Now that I've made the post, the line breaks have got added.

Comment: This is easy to confirm as a bug (for everyone else) by opening the edit menu.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] as no longer reproducible? (at least on my side)

Answer (score 3):

#### More tests

**Test 1**, quoted:

> $$ \text{ this line is centered and the fraction is } \frac{full}{size} $$

```
>  $$ \text{ this line is centered and the fraction is } \frac{full}{size} $$
```

spoilered:

> $$ \text{ in preview, this line is not centered and the fraction has } \frac{reduced}{size} $$

```
>! $$ \text{ in preview, this line is not centered and the fraction has } \frac{reduced}{size} $$
```

**Test 2**, quoted:

> $$ \text{ this is \$\$-delimited } \\
>       \text{ and has multiple lines }
>    $$

```
>  $$ \text{ this is \$\$-delimited } \\
      \text{ and has multiple lines }
   $$
```

spoiler attempt:

> ! $$ \text{ this is \$\$-delimited and has multiple lines } \\
>       \text{ but the exclamation ! point isn't parsed }
>    $$

```
>! $$ \text{ this is \$\$-delimited and has multiple lines } \\
      \text{ but the exclamation ! point isn't parsed }
   $$
```

compulsively-formatted quote attempt:

> $$ \text{ this is \$\$-delimited and has multiple lines } \\
> >     \text{ but only the first right > broket is parsed }
> >  $$

```
>  $$ \text{ this is \$\$-delimited and has multiple lines } \\
>     \text{ but only the first right > broket is parsed }
>  $$
```

**Test 3**, quoted:

> \begin{matrix} \text{ this uses \\begin\{matrix\} without \$\$ } \\
>                   \text{ and has multiple lines }
>    \end{matrix}

```
>  \begin{matrix} \text{ this uses \\begin\{matrix\} without \$\$ } \\
                  \text{ and has multiple lines }
   \end{matrix}
```

spoiler attempt:

> ! \begin{matrix} \text{ this uses \\begin\{matrix\} and has multiple lines } \\
>                   \text{ but the exclamation ! point isn't parsed }
>    \end{matrix}

```
>! \begin{matrix} \text{ this uses \\begin\{matrix\} and has multiple lines } \\
                  \text{ but the exclamation ! point isn't parsed }
   \end{matrix}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer for:

> [All neighbor sum is 0 on a chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78188/all-neighbor-sum-is-0-on-a-chessboard)

to see how to spoiler long MathJax.