# Could we get 'answer edited' notifications?

Tags: feature-request, editing, notifications

While it's not necessarily as useful on other SE sites, "answer edited" notifications would be more useful here, especially on puzzles like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/33133/13535) or others solved progressively.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for notification if any answer on a question you posted get edited?  Notifications of an answer, that you posted, getting edited already exists.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Yes.

Comment: I assumed that a questioner is already notified of answers' revisions. No? This should happen at *all* SE sites, especially before any answer is officially accepted.

Comment: @humn No, that's not how it currently works (but if you think it's how it should work, upvote this question and echo the request elsewhere)!  Users should have the ability to turn off those kinds of notifications, per-SE, as I'd probably only use it here.

Comment: Answerers should also get "question edited" notifications. (Or do they? (Why) hasn't this come up before?)

Answer (score 2):

Until there's a better answer, the best workaround is to @mention the question-asker's name in a comment manually posted on an answer when edited.

Comment: One thing to note is that, while you're not notified per se, the question *does* get bumped back to the top of the main page whenever anything is edited.

Comment: Negative vote because:  1) The best workaround only works when an answer-editor or a knowing bystander thinks of using it, which seems to be extremely rare and is likely to remain sporadic even if some people make an effort to educate everyone. 2) I assume this answer was put here to gather negative votes, which support the proposition in question.

Comment: It was put here not to attract negative votes but to be informative for people who come looking for the same thing. This workaround is not a satisfactory solution for the reasons you mentioned and that's why the request is being made in the first place.  Upvoting the question would be more productive in supporting the proposal.

Comment: Does @-ing the questioner work every time?  The automatic @-recognition *seems* to only offer the questioner's name when they have commented on the answer. If that's true, the alerting comment must often be made on the original question, not the answer (And oops about the negative vote, I do appreciate the information here.)