# The MathJax sandbox

Tags: discussion, mathjax, sandbox

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup \def\safeMathJax{\text{\endgroup error}}$

$$The\ MathJax\ Sandbox$$

It's occasionally difficult to figure out if your MathJax will work in a post, even if it works/doesn't work in the preview. Also, sometimes you want to experiment with stuff that you *might* use in a puzzle. So... it's always good to have a sandbox. This is primarily for testing $MathJax$, but other formatting tests are also acceptable.

Please try to avoid stuff that will crash people's browsers, okay? Thanks :)

$%invisibletext$

<sup>**MathJax incidentals (copied from @humn)**</sup>

<sub>If you use MathJax-modifying commands such as
$\texttt{\def}$ or $\texttt{\let}$ or $\texttt{\newcommand}$
please keep modifications from leaking to other posts by using
$\texttt{\begingroup} \raise1.7ex\strut$ and $\texttt{\endgroup}$.
The following template is good for this:</sub>

```
  $\require{begingroup} \begingroup \def\safeMathJax{\text{\endgroup error}}$

  [Answer that includes MathJax code with \def or \let or \newcommand]

  $\endgroup \safeMathJax$
```

<sub>If all goes well, the answer will end with
(as at the end of this post):
$\kern2em\bbox[mistyrose]{\color{red}{\text{\safeMathJax}}} \raise-.8ex\strut$


If
$\texttt{\endgroup}$ is not used successfully,
the template is meant to show:
$~~\text{\endgroup error} \raise-.8ex\strut$


Before posting an answer, be sure to test it
on a freshly loaded browser page.
Might also need to reload the page while editing,
as inadvertent indiscretions in one edit
can pervert MathJax results during later edits.</sub>

$\endgroup \safeMathJax$

Comment: NB: On both this post and on Mith's blank answer, I have not edited in the begingroup/endgroup. Please use it for future posts

Comment: Further reading: [_Spoiler markup does not break line for series of MathJax equations in post previews_](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3007/spoiler-markup-does-not-break-line-for-series-of-mathjax-equations-in-post-previ)

Comment: There also exists a [MathJax tutorial on Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). I think it makes sense to put this link here.

Comment: And now there's a MathJax FAQ here on Puzzling Meta itself: [A brief guide to MathJax for PSE users](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7421/44357) :)

Answer (score 6):

$%Is it possible to have an entirely blank post?$

Comment: I refreshed the page because of this one...

Answer (score 2):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup \def\safeMathJax{\text{\endgroup error}}$

This is an answer.

$\endgroup \safeMathJax$

Comment: Flagged as not an answer!

Answer (score 0):

### Testing special characters

Unicode: ߥ DDagger

HTML: ‡

MathJax $\ddagger$

Answer (score 0):

This is a test post for hovering text in comments. Ignore me.

Comment: A hint to know if you’ve found the expected answer: [hover or click spoiler](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+expected+strategy+guarantees+Van+Helsing+and+Jonathan+a+100%25+win+rate. "The expected strategy guarantees Van Helsing and Jonathan a 100% win rate.")