# Where to go to get feedback on questions before posting

Tags: discussion

I would like to get feedback on the questions I post here before posting them, so that I can tweak the difficulty and make the questions more fun to solve.

What is the best way to go about this?

I have run my questions past my friends in real life, but none of them are 'expert' puzzle solvers and this doesn't result in the best quality feedback for harder/longer puzzles.

I mostly plan to create word connection puzzles, and maybe some discover-the-rules type puzzles as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Chat!

Puzzling has a fairly active [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair). You can pop in whenever you'd like and simply ask for puzzle feedback/testers. If the puzzle is short enough you may be able to paste all the important parts in chat. Some add-ons:

- [The MathJax Sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6052/the-mathjax-sandbox). Despite the name, this is a sandbox for any sort of formatting. If your puzzle **requires particular formatting** as part of its presentation, this is a good option. Please *also* post a link in chat, as the sandbox is not regularly checked.
- [One-Time Secret](https://onetimesecret.com/). This site allows you to create a link which will work for *only* one person. The link will lead to a textbox, in which you can put anything you'd like, including links elsewhere. If you want to **keep your puzzle private before release**, this is a good option. A normal workflow would be to ask in chat for a tester, then send them a link; they may send feedback by another link or publically in chat. [Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62784926#62784926).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look to try this out with some puzzles currently in the works!